# Restrictions vs Permissions

Tags: permissions

This is a fairly strange question, but I was just trying to work out how exactly to create the right "permissions" for my users and came slowly to the conclusion that "restrictions" might be a better approach, except that I cannot see anything about this method online. So I assume I am doing something logically wrong.

I have a system of shipments.
It has several types of users/roles/perspectives(?).

- Admin (See all)
- Supplier (Shipment Owner)
- Factory (Shipment Receiver)

They can all ultimately edit the shipments. *But* the supplier is only allowed to edit under certain conditions, like for example that the shipment hasn't been shipped already! The admin and factory worker however, can do whatever they want. Also suppliers and factories can only edit shipments related to them.

So at first I came up with these permissions:

- EditShipments (*admin* and *factory* and *Supplier*)

But wait, that works for admins, but I don't want factories editing the shipments of other factories (perhaps through editing POST data or playing with the API). Same for the supplier.

- EditAnyShipment (*admin*)
- EditOwnReceivedShipments  (*factory*)
- EditOwnSentShipments  (*supplier*)

Now when doing the edit, I have to determine if the user is the owner, and use that permission, or if the user is an admin and just let them do what they want.
This is ok.. I guess. But I have to write some logic to determine which permission is actually valid based on the situation. That's quite annoying - and I don't have a solution except "functional permissions" which I have no idea how to implement properly.

Let's continue. Now I want to restrict suppliers to only be able to edit non-finished shipments.

- EditAnyShipment (*admin*)
- EditOwnReceivedShipments  (*factory*)
- EditOwnUnFinishedSentShipments  (*supplier*)

Now lets say I want to also only allow suppliers to be able to edit shipments that are not shipping within the next week. Now what.

- EditOwnUnFinishedSentShipmentsThatAreNotShippingInTheNextWeek  (*supplier*)

Right? So this gets ridiculous as the requirements continue to change.

So coming to my current weird solution whereby what is written above are "permissions" which are "added", instead looking from the other direction and making them "Restrictions" which would be "subtracted".

(Admin doesn't need anything)
* EditOnlyIfRecievedToMyFactoryShipment (*Factory*)
* EditOnlyIfIsUnfinishedShipment (*Supplier*)
* EditOnlyIfIsNotShippingInAWeekShipment (*Supplier*)

What am I doing here and how does one implement this? Is there some kind of design pattern around this idea?

Comment: Generally, it's much easier to add unintentional security holes the way you suggest. Suppose you think of something new that only admin can do - you'd have to go through all other users and add the new restriction. Suppose you add a new user - it's much easier to accidentally miss a restriction (and less visible), than to accidentally add a permission. And if you try and plug by automatically giving all restrictions by default... you're basically back to using permissions.

Comment: I ended up using a mix of the two. So for example things like `SkipOtherSystemCheck` is a permission only admins have, to allow them to make edits regardless of the `other system`